# Working with templates in ember-models-table

Tags: templates, ember.js, components

I am using ember-models-table (https://github.com/onechiporenko/ember-models-table) and I want to customize the output of a table cell. As the documentation suggests I tried with assigning templates and components to columns in the columns definition.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    columnDefs
    {
        "propertyName": "id",
        "title": "ID",
    },
    {
        "propertyName": "name",
        "title": "Name",
    },
    {
        "propertyName": "postTypeId",
        "title": "Post Type",
        "template": "ember-models-table/column/enumType", // can be template or component
    }
});
```

So I am not talking about the ember-models-table component but about custom templates / component that can be assigned to specific column as can be seen in column 3 in my code snipplet. Whereas it seems that to a template only a record reference is passed, the docs (http://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/#/examples) say that to a component a table, a column, a record and a data reference is passed but what I need is

a) the specific value (or model property) I defined within the columnDefs in the controller (this is because I want to use this template / component with many models and different property names, so I can't hardcode the property name in the template / component)

b) the ability to pass arbitrary data to the column's component (here I am talking about component only because it seems that it is possible with components to pass something in with the data attribute, but I could not figure out how to do it)

Hope my problem is getting a little bit clearer and would appreciate every suggestion.

P.S If there's a better way to format the output within a table cell (for example by somehow assigning a helper to the cell's value) please tell me.

Comment: If your scenarios need templates too much, you should better to lookup [ember-contextual-table](https://tubitak-bilgem-yte.github.io/ember-contextual-table/#/cell-customization)

Comment: @Mannimalte hasn't the answer I provided helped you at all?

Comment: Absolutely, it has! I simply didn't work on that problem the last day. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's ok; I was just curious about that; good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your case; but please take a look at the dummy application I have created in this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7e78603eea6237652b67f41068e16b61?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). I have passed `my-custom-property-for-component` in column definition for the custom component (`my-component`) and table wide custom property named `tableWideCustomProperty` to `models-table`.

You can retrieve these properties from within `my-component` as follows:

Retrieving `my-custom-property-for-component`: `column.my-custom-property-for-component` because column definition is passed with the name `column` to the custom component.

Retrieving `tableWideCustomProperty`: `table.tableWideCustomProperty` because `models-table` itself is passed with the name `table` to the custom component.

As you can see, you have access to the `table`, `record`, `data` and `column` attributes within the custom component defined within column definition.

Comment: Thank you so much – especially for the twiddle. It's the best way to show how things work!

Answer (score 0):

While I may not 100% understand your use case, I'm assuming rendering the tables on your routes.  One method would be defining the column definitions on a controller property and pass it with the model to the component.

app/controllers/person.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
columnDefs: [
    {
        "propertyName": "id",
        "title": "ID"
    },
    {
        "propertyName": "firstName",
        "title": "First Name"
    },
    {
        "propertyName": "lastName",
        "title": "Last Name"
    }]
});
```

app/models/person.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    firstName:     DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:      DS.attr('string')
});
```

app/routes/person.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('person');
  }
})
```

app/templates/person.hbs

```
{{models-table
        data=model
       columns=columnDefs}}
```

You can add any options (template, sortedBy, etc) to the objects as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help but what you described is what I am already doing. Obviously I did make clear enough what I was trying to do. So I updated my question to be more precise.